# Add Geography Column to an existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server, spatial-database, geography-data-type

I Have an existing table `GPSPosition` which has a coma seperated LatLong column. I have attempted to add a geography column using the query:

```
 alter table GPSPositions add geographyColumn as geography::STGeomFromText('POINT('+convert(varchar(20),RIGHT(LatLong, Charindex(',', LatLong) - 1))+' '+convert(varchar(20),LEFT(LatLong, Charindex(',', LatLong) - 1) )+')',4326)
```

This creates the column but I get problems with the table when I attempt to query it:

> System.FormatException: 24141: A number is expected at position 14 of the >input. The input has ,-1.8635.

How would I construct the query to add the column correctly?

Answer (score -1):

(GEOGRAPHY::Point(Latitude , Longitude , 4326) )

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/point-geography-data-type